# MPI issues with Xcode5

Tags: c++, macos, xcode5, mpi

I am trying to compile a simple Hello World program in Xcode5 using MPI. But Xcode doesn't recognize the header:

```
#include <mpi.h>
```

Searching online, it seems that Xcode5 doesn't work well with an MPI compiler.

Is there a way to make them work together? If so, can you point me into the right direction?
If not, how do you compile MPI on your Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it is possible to compile MPI with Xcode and that I've done it before, but it's been a long time since I tried so I won't be able to answer that part of your question.

However, I think most people that are writing MPI programs don't bother with an IDE (like Xcode, Eclipse, etc.) because it's usually a bit of a pain to take advantage of most of the features of IDEs when you're primarily using a non-standard library as MPI is. Most of us just use the command line and call `mpicc` and `mpiexec` directly.

However, that being said, I know that Eclipse does have a [Parallel Tools Platform](https://www.eclipse.org/ptp/) that does some magic with MPI and other parallel programming libraries. There have been quite a few questions about it on this site that you can browse around for and you can check out their website for lots of information as well.

Comment: Thanks Wesley! And thanks for editing the post. I will check it out, and give it a try to command line.

Comment: Also, I know that you can do it with previous versions of Xcode, but it seems that since Xcode 5 its not possible, or at least I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: If you're new to MPI, a good tutorial that I've found is here: http://mpitutorial.com/ (no, it's not the same Wes).

Comment: Great! Thanks, I will certainly check it out.